# Adb shell command to disable keyboard suggestions on android

Tags: android, adb, e2e-testing, detox

So I am trying to disable keyboard suggestions and contact suggestions programmatically on an aosp api 29 emulator (for e2e screenshot test purposes) which I belive should start like `adb shell settings put ...` but I cannot seem to find a command to switch that off as my google fu is not strong enough. Would be amazing if someone here knows the answer to that.

So what I would like to achieve is to disable the suggestion part in the image shown below
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AVD from android SDK, in wizard configuration there is `show advance settings` that let you enable keyboard input or not.
And if you are using another emulator apps there should be an address like `~/.android/avd/<The_Device_Name>/config.ini` in your home directory and then Change the below setting to be:
`hw.keyboard=yes`

also do not forget to restart the emulator after changes.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. I think this would't really help me as I still want the keyboard input to be enabled but want to disable the suggestion. Ive updated the original question to reflect this better. Thanks